# How to configure logstash forwarder in windows for event logs (.evtx files)

Tags: windows, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I have configured logstash, elastic search and kibana on a Linux machine.
I tried to send logs from the Linux machine, it was successfully sent and working fine (Apache logs, system logs, log4j logs). I also tried sending it from a Windows machine. Normal logs are working fine but Windows Event Logs are not working (.evtx files).

Any idea on why it is working from Linux but not Windows?

Comment: Please can we see code, config - something?

Comment: You're basically saying "evtx files don't work". What does that mean, specifically? What happens? What did you expect would happen?

Comment: windows event log file format is .evtx. i trying to read this file my logstash forwarder is unable to read that.